# Is the a specific way to restore flowing water after having shut off water at the water meter outside my home?

Tags: plumbing, water, pipe

Is there a specific way to turn the water back on other than flipping the switch @ the water meter? All of my indoor faucets are closed. I live in the Richmond,TX a suburb of Houston. We are experiencing a freeze. This question is for when the freeze is over.

Comment: Did you drain the system? You're going to have a different problem if you shut off the water but left all the lines full.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Water is under pressure. If the valve's open it goes. Also, I'm not familiar with water meters which control flow. Is that a thing?

Comment: At least open all faucets with the water off.  Any pipes that might freeze should be drained.  When turning on the water the faucets should be open to allow air to escape.

Comment: If you shut off the water because of the freeze, to avoid burst pipes, then you should *immediately* open all the faucets/spigots/whatever inside the house. Since the water is "off" this will drain left-over water out of the system, preventing that from freezing and bursting your pipes. Once you have all the water drained, close all the fixtures again except the lowest one.

Answer (score 1):

If you turned off the water to avoid a freeze causing burst pipes, there are steps you should take:

1. Turn off the "main" water valve.
2. Open all the "fixtures" inside the house. Faucets, spigots, tubs, showers, whatever. This will allow *unpressurized* water to drain out of the pipes.
3. Wait until water stops flowing. If water flows "strongly" from a fixture, you probably didn't shut off the main valve. Close the fixture and goto step 1.
4. Once water flow stops, close all the fixtures.

Now your system is "empty." There may still be places with water trapped in the pipes, but the pipes are going to be mostly full of air and "stuff."

When you are no longer worried about the freeze, you can turn the water back on. When you turn the water back on, you have to worry about "stuff" in your water pipes. The surge of pressurized water coming into (partially) empty pipes can pick up any "stuff" and carry it to the fixtures. That may result in a faucet or showerhead that stops flowing, or is partially blocked, or something. The solution is to take off just that fixture and shake, rinse, or blow the stuff out the back of the showerhead or filter. (Faucet filter/aerators are the little "screen" you see at the end, plus maybe some plastic bits inside. Showerheads are showerheads. Bathtub fixtures generally aren't filtered - they're all about moving a lot of water quickly.)

BTW, when I say "stuff" I mean "stuff." It's not a euphemism, it's an expression of uncertainty. Stuff might be bits of plumbing material (glue, tape, compound) or rust or scale or shards of pipe plastic or sawdust from construction, or it might be bits of whatever is in your water supply, or it might be baby alligators (that's usually the sewer, not the supply lines, but hey! Houston has no zoning, so anything goes, right?)

If your house is built using a "manifold" system, where water is controlled at a central point and then flows throughout the house in "home runs" that all connect directly back to the manifold, you can probably get by with turning off and draining only the lines that (1) go outside; or (2) are routed through exterior walls. But also note that manifold systems are almost always done with PEX pipes. You would basically do the same things, but just for certain lines.

Ecnerwal makes the point in a comment that you don't want to drain *all* the water out of the hot water heater without shutting it off. This is unlikely, for most houses, due to how they are installed. But absolutely true. Be sure to either (1) turn off the HWH, or (2) prevent it from draining (there should be valves on the lines leading from/to the HWH).

Comment: If you don't **turn off the water heater** before draining the system, you can buy a new one of those, or at least new elements if electric. A gas powered one might well destroy its tank, while the electrics will usually just destroy their elements. You might get away with it if the way you drain the system doesn't drain the water heater, but better to just shut it down unless you are 100% sure it's full of water and going to stay that way (and not freeze due to power or gas loss and optimistic location.)